# How to enable SFTP error status in RHEL7.1?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, rhel7

Here is the problem that I am facing. I have a provisioning server which runs a perl script to upload and download certain files in a regular interval using sftp. The sftp command is executed in batch mode and looks like this

```
my $sftpCmd = `sftp -o BatchMode=yes -b $batchFile $userAtHost 2>&1`;
```

Typically the batch file would contain commands like

```
cd /someFolder/
get someFile
```

The problem is when we used to run the sftp command in rhel6.3 we used to get proper reason for any failure cases. Also we used this failure reason, captured as string, to increment different failure statistics. for example,

```
sftp -o BatchMode=yes -b batchFile.txt user1@localhost
Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
File "/someFolder/someFile" not found.
```

Now because of business requirements we have upgraded our system to rhel7.1. And somehow the extra failure information is getting suppressed in rhel7.1. The output in rhel7.1 looks like this

```
sftp -o BatchMode=yes -b batchFile.txt user1@localhost
File "/someFolder/someFile" not found.
```

Can anyone suggest how to enable printing this missing information?
I have one solution in mind, which works but is not so pretty for users. If sftp is run in verbose mode it prints all debug information along with the missing strings. But it unnecessarily populates the log files with unwanted data.

```
sftp -v -o BatchMode=yes -b batchFile.txt user1@localhost
```

Any clean solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The sftp command is supposed to be interactive. A suggestion : Have you tried using scp instead ?